# Dropdown select menu reset to default option selection after form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I click the submit button it does filter the selections according to the selected brand but the dropdown option reset to the first option
`

```
**<%= form_tag(products_path, :method => "get",
    class: 'navbar-form navbar-left') do %>
<div class="input-group">
    <%= search_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search", class: "form-control" %>
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <%= button_tag "search", :class => 'btn btn-info glyphicon glyphicon-search',:name => nil%>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <%= search_field_tag :min, params[:min], placeholder: "min", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= search_field_tag :max, params[:max], placeholder: "max", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <% brands_array = Brand.all.map { |brand| [brand.name, brand.id] } %>
    <%= select_tag :brand_id, options_for_select(brands_array) %>
</div>
<% end %>**
```

`

Comment: When you want to represent data in a form element you have to pass that data to the form first. So what is your controller code that passes instance variables to this? So the form element will default to the data in the variable. If the variable is empty because it is unset then it will default to what ever you set in the form element.

Comment: Please edit your question to add your controller code.

Comment: thank you every one

Comment: I solved it by adding param[:brand_id] to options_for_select method as the following           <% brands_array = Brand.all.map { |brand| [brand.name, brand.id] } %>
    <%= select_tag :brand_id, options_for_select(brands_array,params[:brand_id]) %>